# Make an search engine and get result based on the frequency of search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to make a search for my website to search the user form my database. Let say I want maybe the most popular or searched user be search priority instead of some no name guy and without using other search engine api/framework. I rather doing this with my finger. So how can i acheive it?I using php for server side ,javascript client side,mysql for database.

Comment: Can you share any code that you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: look at sphinx or elastic search

Comment: have you used google?
since you asked such general question i assume you are not able to implement such feature. quit now.

Comment: Erm im still thinking how to acheive it so doesn't have any source code=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database add `score column` and add +1 to it whenever user is visited from search results.

After that simply add `ORDER BY score DESC` to your query when displaying results.